# How to set up colors in tool windows in Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea, android-studio-3.3

Just updated Android Studio to 3.3 and saw that some colors in tool windows became hardly readable in dark theme. That happens in Find and Shelve windows (see screenshot). I'd like to change text color for secondary text, but cannot find an option for that.

[image: Find window]

Comment: Is it possible to share idea.log ("Help | Show Log in...") after restarting IDE?

Comment: @y.bedrov it is pretty long. Please see here https://pastebin.com/u6fSAhHu